# How to hide Explorer window in VS Code in Zen mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When

1. Zen mode is opened (<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) and
2. Explorer window is opened (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd>)

how can the explorer window be closed without leaving the Zen mode?

Both <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> exits the Zen mode and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd> does nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility`, which is <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> by default.